# Good Web-book application stack?

Tags: django, pdf

I'm wondering is there any open-source solution for web-book creation like "The Django Book" has?

It has a really usable web interface, comments system (with comments targeted on certain peace of text), pdf nightly auto-generation, with whole content pulled from repo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only Django based one I know of is [openbookplatform](http://code.google.com/p/openbookplatform/source/browse/) but it is an abandoned project and hasn't even been updated for Django 1.x.  However, it might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

The [Book module](http://drupal.org/node/284) that forms a part of [Drupal Core](http://drupal.org/features) is reportedly a pretty good tool for collaborative book authoring.

Caveat: While I've used Drupal to create a couple of websites, I've not used the Book module myself.